# Accessing QML canvas from javascript in QT

Tags: javascript, qt, canvas, qml

I am trying to create very simple application in **QT QML** using **QtQuick 2.7**. I added on the *canvas* one *rectangle*, and after pushing the *button* I want to add another *rectangle*. Problem is, that the *rectangle* which should appear after *button* click is not created (I cannot see it on *canvas*), but console.log() output `Button 1 cliceked` I see. What I am doing wrong? Is there any need to refresh the canvas or something? My code is:

```
Page1Form {
    property alias canvas: canvas
    button1.onClicked: {
        console.log("Button 1 clicked.");
        var ct = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ct.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
        ct.fillRect(50, 50, 10, 10);//this doesnt work
    }
    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        x: 16
        y: 39
        width: 342
        height: 517
        onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
                ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Canvas` only repaints after being asked to. See the [documentation for the paint() signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#paint-signal):

> This signal is emitted when the region needs to be rendered. If a context is active it can be referenced from the context property.
>
> This signal can be triggered by markdirty(), requestPaint() or by changing the current canvas window.

So, after doing your drawing, call `requestPaint()`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Canvas {
            id: canvas
            width: parent.width
            height: 300
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 1, 1);
                ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Add"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Button 1 clicked.");
                var ct = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ct.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
                ct.fillRect(50, 50, 10, 10);//this doesnt work
                canvas.requestPaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although, this seems to me like an odd way of doing it; usually you respond to the canvas telling you that it's ready to paint via the `paint()` signal, not the other way around. What this means in practice is that your blue rectangles will be painted *before* (and hence underneath) the one in the `onPaint` handler.